# sendRedirect() doens't work

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I looked for a solution on this forum, but i didn't find anything that suits my problem.

I have a very simplce code

a jsp page

```
<html>
<body>
<jsp:include page="/servletName"/>
</body>
</html>
```

and a servlet

```
@WebServlet("/servletName")
public class reindirizzaController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public reindirizzaController() {
        super();        
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      String redirectURL = "http://www.google.it";
      response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);       
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

}
```

No redirect is done. I'm stuck in the jsp page and i get no error. I also tried to add `return;` after the response.

Comment: Redirect is handled through response headers - it can only happen BEFORE any output is written in response body. After response body is started any redirect actions will be ignored.

Comment: Why would you want to *include* google rather than provide a *link* to google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are calling the servlet through `Include`, it does not make you redirect. It simply ignores.

From docs of [`include()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29)

> includes the content of a resource (servlet, JSP page, HTML file) in the response. In essence, this method enables programmatic server-side includes.
>
> The ServletResponse object has its path elements and parameters remain unchanged from the caller's. The included servlet cannot change the response status code or set headers; **any attempt to make a change is ignored.**

Answer (score 0):

First, it is bad practice to call a servlet from a jsp. As you are using `@WebServlet("/servletName")`, you can directly call it at `http://host/context/servletName`

If you really need to call it from a jsp, you must forward to the servlet instead of including it as Suresh Atta explained. So you should use :

```
<jsp:forward page="/servletName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a JSP include directive, you're essentially plopping the code you're including right on the page.  In your example, you would be doing the sendRedirect in your JSP.  Even if you got the redirect to work miraculously, you would get an error saying that your response has already been committed.  This is because by the time your browser loads the JSP, it is already reading from the server's response.  The server cannot send another response while it is already sending a response to your browser.

One way to approach this is instead of doing an include directive, create a form with your servlet path as the action.  Something like:

```
<form name="someForm" action="/servletPath/servletName">
    <!-- some stuff here if you want -->
</form>
```

And then in your body tag, have it submit the form on load:

```
<body onLoad="document.someForm.submit();">
```